# merge photos, photo, and pictures tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are tags for `photos`, `photo`, and `pictures`. These should probably be all `photos`.

Comment: mmmmm... you picked the plural. perfect!

Comment: If someone has a problem with *one specific photo*, it's probably off-topic for this site. :)

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the [pictures](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) posts is about image files in general, not just photos. I'll make the [photo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) synonym for [photos](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos). I'll look to see if [pictures](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) should be synonym'd to [images](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images).

***Update***: [photo](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) is now a synonym for [photos](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos). I changed all of the [pictures](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) to [images](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) but I'm not sure it should be a synonym. I also changed all but one [image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) to [images](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images); that one was about making an "image" of the phone, but other tags existed which covered the topic, so I just removed it.

Comment: Good work.  Someone could definitely tag "picture[s]" and mean "photo[s]" so I agree it's not necessarily a synonym of "image[s]".